# How to get access to web-folder in Twig in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a Twig template in my bundle and I want to get access to the web-folder in my Symfony application where my picture is I want to show. The web-folder is in the main directory. The link to my image is coming from my database:

```
uploads/documents/image1.jpg
```

In my Twig template I have to define my two variables:

```
<img src="/{{ var.uploadDir }}{{ var.path }}" width="300px" height="150px">
```

but the image is not shown. It says that the URL is not found. Is it possible to get access to the web path without using "assets"?

Comment: Use asset("uploads/documents/image1.jpg")

Comment: I want to make it variable so its not possible for my application to use fixed names for the image

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood exactly what you want, but if you want to deal only with variables, you may want to put `uploads/documents/image1.jpg` into you parameters file and call it into your twig. But I don't think it's a real good idea because what are u going to do with handred images

Comment: The images I want to show are coming from my database. The "uploads/documents/image1.jpg" was only the example which comes completely from my database. But it isnt shown on my website because it says that the path is not correct!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try passing the variables through the `asset` function?

```
<img src="{{ asset(var.uploadDir ~ var.path) }}" width="300px" height="150px">
```

Theoretically though, this would yield the same result, so you need to examine a few things:

1. You *must* make the `web/` folder your docroot in the Apache settings
2. Verify the file exists in that path (for example, `web/uploads/documents/image1.jpg` must exist)
3. Verify that the concatenation of `var.uploadDir` and `var.path` actually yield a valid path. Maybe you forgot somewhere in your code that you actually don't have a trailing slash or leading slash in each respective variable. Then, `var.uploadDir ~ var.path` could yield `/uploadsdocuments/image1.jpg` which is obviously incorrect.

Comment: Your first point is excellent, and something that I think a lot of people aren't aware of - the ability to concatenate strings inside Twig's `asset()` function.  Symfony's documentation always has hardcoded values here, and the `~` operator itself isn't discussed.  If the original poster would like a reference, here's a link to the Twig documentation explaining it:  http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators

Comment: @JasonRoman Yes I highly recommend a thorough reading of the Twig and Doctrine documentations - they are an integral part of Symfony and knowing their full feature set is important.

Comment: THANK YOU! Didn't know that I can put the variables into an asset function and connet it only with a "~". GREAT!